# Having trouble scrolling to top of page while using scroll-snap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm using scroll-snap to snap to different sections to create a nice slideshow effect while scrolling. I want to have a button at the bottom that scrolls back to the top when clicked, but recommendations I have seen for this functionality are not working.

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 5. I'm assuming the scroll-snap is causing a problem, or maybe the the window thinks it's already at the top of the page for some reason.

```js
$("#return-to-top-button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    return false;
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body {
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

div {
 scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 100vh;
}

section {
 height: 100vh;
 scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.scroll-one {
    background-color: red;
}

.scroll-two {
    background-color: blue;
}

.scroll-three {
    background-color: green;
}

.scroll-four {
    background-color: orange;
}

.scroll-five {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
 <section>
  <p>Section 1</p>
 </section>

 <section class="scroll-one">
  <p>Section 2</p>
 </section>

 <section class="scroll-two">
  <p>Section 3</p>
 </section>

 <section class="scroll-three">
  <p>Section 4</p>
 </section>

 <section class="scroll-four">
  <p>Section 5>/p>
 </section>

 <section class="scroll-five">
  <p>Section 6</p>
  <a id="return-to-top-button" href="#">Return to top</a>
 </section>
</div>
```